# Different CSS Display on Ubuntu and Windows with same code and browser

Tags: html, css, ubuntu, firefox

I have encountered a curious thing: a part of a html code shows differently in the same browsers; I am guessing that it has to do with the operating system, but maybe not.

Here are the screenshots. The code is an identical repository in gitlab. The browser is Firefox, but we tried with other browsers too, to the same result.

[Ubuntu version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSMTZ.png):

[image]

[Windows version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEzyD.jpg):

[image]

The part in question is the red text, in ubuntu its more on the left of the div. All windows are at 100% zoom. The browser versions are the same, Firefox 102.0.

Comment: Probably just different screen resolutions.

Comment: @Quentin it probably is! i will try it out and post an update

Comment: Are you using the same font? Also, you might want to consider that Windows renders fonts differently than Ubuntu does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The issue was a missing font.** We use Verdana and it was not installed on the ubuntu system. After installing verdana everything looked finally the same.